# Using higher order functions to loop nested arrays

Tags: arrays

this is my array

```
array = [
[{}, {}, {}, {}],
[{}, {}, {}, {}], 
[{}, {}, {}, {}],
... ]
```

I'm trying to find if a nested obj property is equal to a certain value

`let sqr = board.forEach(subArr => subArr.filter(obj => obj.idx === 1))`

when I console.log(sqr) I get undefined but I know there is a obj with that property/value pair.

what am I missing?

Comment: What language are you using?  You should use it as a tag.

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything (implicitly returns `undefined`). You're better off using a simple `for` loop and return from it when the condition is met.